# SBT + Idea 2.5 := Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Part of the code is red

```
name := "ScalaProject - 0.7(version)"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

**Cannot resolve symbol :=**

**Cannot resolve symbol scalaVersion**

Problem at the beginning of writing a project, 
in the file - build.sbt

Tried several versions, did not help

Tell me please what to do?

Comment: Try building the sbt project.

Comment: Make sure you can build project by SBT from command line. And try to [re-import project from build.sbt file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#import_sbt) in IDE.